# How to restore the EEL python web session

Tags: python, eel

I am using EEL package in python to create web UI. But there are some situtations when because the errors in python the session is closed. When such situation arises I want to restore the session in the same web window or tab and run the python scripts app.Py from the scratch ? How to achieve this functionality . I am using error handling in each function in python but there could be any bug in future possible.